# While running robot framework scripts, getting error: default adapter failed

Tags: automation, pycharm, operating-system, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I'm getting errors while running below mentioned RF scripts. How can I resolve this issue, I don't see any problem with the chrome/web driver version. Please let me know

ERROR:  bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adapter failed.

Chrome version: 91.0.4472.124

Chrome We driver: 91

IDE: Pycharm

Machine: VM

```
Library SeleniumLibrary
*** Test Cases ***
User must sign in to check out
    [Documentation]    This is some basic info about the test
    [Tags]  Smoke
    open browser    http://www.amazon.com   chrome
    Wait Until Page Contains    Amazon
    Input Text    id=twotabsearchtextbox    Ferrari 485
    Click Button    xpath =//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']
    Wait Until Page Contains    results for "Ferrari 485
    CLICK LINK  xpath=//*[@id="n/3073871"]/span/a/span
    Click Link  xpath=//input[@id='add-to-cart-button']
    Page Should Contain Element    ap_signala_pagelet_title
    Element Text Should Be  ap_signala_pagelet_title    sign In
    close browser
*** Keywords ***
```

Comment: Is that error coming from a keyword, or does it happen before the test starts or after the tests are finished?

Comment: The above error is observed after the test starts